# Other half of Gronwall

Tags: integral-inequality

I am looking to show that if y(t) is continuous on (a, b) and satisfies

$$y(t)\leq H+K\int_{t}^{t_{0}} y(s)ds,\quad\forall\ a<t\leq t_0$$

where $t_0 \in (a,b)$, then

$$y(t)\leq He^{K(t_0-t)},\quad\forall\ a<t\leq t_0$$

Comment: Do you want $h(s)$ and not $y(s)$ under your integral sign?

Comment: In this case what is the function $h$ ?

Comment: That is a great question. Perhaps that is the trouble with it. Let's suppose that was a mistake. I will change the question to represent that.